# Alternative phrasing to "inclination notwithstanding"

Tags: synonyms

I am trying to write a Statement of Purpose for graduate school and am unable to phrase my research interests in a satisfactory way. I wish to express something along the lines of *"my specific areas of interest are X and Y, particularly in the context of Z. My inclination towards these areas **notwithstanding** at the heart of my research concentration lies a more general interest in A*".

I want something similar to *in addition to* or *apart from* but with the inclusiveness and the contrast provided by this particular phrasing.

Any hints?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to describe your main research interest as an "inclination" only? Are you hedging your bets in case the school wishes you to change track? And is area A so different from X/Y/Z that you require the force of "notwithstanding" or "despite"?

Comment: @Cargill: The sentiment I wanted to express was that although my current areas of interest are X and Y, I'm not necessarily restricted to those. The sentence is supposed to 'zoom out' to a superset of my niche area of interest (current). Since the areas share a superset-subset relation, I agree that 'notwithstanding' is a far from correct word choice, which is why I am looking for alternatives. Sorry for being unclear.

Comment: No - not unclear at all.  I was just confirming that it wasn't: "Molluscs and starfish in the context of long-term coral reef health, but with a general interest in 15thC Persian flute music", or something of that order.

Answer (score 1):

Try *despite*:

> My specific areas of interest are X and Y, particularly in the context of Z. Despite my inclination towards these areas, my research primarily focuses on A...

I changed your second sentence beyond *despite*: the sentence struck me as unnecessarily verbose.